# Different position on Safari vs Firefox

Tags: html, css, position

I have a text label that is positioned differently on Safari and Firefox.

This is how it looks like on Firefox:

[image: Firefox]

This is how it looks on Safari:

[image: Safari]

The HTML:

```html
<label class="input">
    <input class="input_field" placeholder=" ">
    <span class="input_label">Enter url</span>
</label>
```

CSS:

```css
:root {
  --size-bezel: .5rem;
}
.input {
  position: relative;
}
.input_label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 3px;
  top: -8px;
  padding: calc(var(--size-bezel) * 0.75) calc(var(--size-bezel) * 0.5);
  margin: calc(var(--size-bezel) * 0.75 + 3px) calc(var(--size-bezel) * 0.5);
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: var(--color-background-card);
}
```

- Changing the `top: -8px;` to something lower did not reposition the element on Safari
- I've tried relative position with no luck

Comment: were you able to fix this, i am facing same issue

Comment: @opensource-developer Hi, this is a while ago, so I looked at my commits to see what I did. I didn't really find a suitable fix, but you can see it [here](https://github.com/Jomy10/qr-web/commit/6ee8655d4c3095a6f9b72552f0c72e77a0f9366a). Basically, I just added a negative margin when the browser is Safari. Not ideal though :/

Answer (score 1):

To avoid problems among browsers, I would recommend add some reset CSS code.

### 1. Reset margin and padding

```
 *,
 *::before,
 *::after {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

### 2. Include [normalize CSS](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/8.0.1/normalize.css) to your project

You can install it by running `npm install normalize.css`

Unfortunately, I can't test it out on browsers right now, but most likely you can compare what are the default CSS values every browser has in Developer Tools

Comment: Great suggestion. Unfortunatly, it did not help in this situation.

Comment: @Jomy what are the values you have in the Developer tools for both browsers?